# Como criar um banco de dados local no SQL server 2016?

Tags: sql-server

Instalei a dias o SSMS 2016 (Sql Server Management Studio) há dias em meu PC mas não consigo criar um banco de dados local.

A única coisa que faço é conectar com um banco de dados que eu hospedei no azure, mas quando vou para criar um BD local dá erro com a seguinte mensagem:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to WKSIPLAB_A10.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The network path was not found

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: Só com estas informações ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar, tem que detalhar o que está fazendo.

Comment: O que estou fazendo é criar um banco de dados local  no sql server 2016 apartir do data engine claro, mas não consigo....

Comment: A pergunta é clara e suficiente. Eu podia entender e responder. Desconcordo com o fechamento.

Answer (score 2):

Precisa de um SQL Server "engine" para criar bases de dados. SSMS é somente uma ferramenta de cliente. Você pode instalar SQL Server Express no seu PC, é gratis.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx